# importxml function in google sheets not working for specific website

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use importxml function in google sheets to import a price for a specific kind of security which is called a structured note. Many banks offer these products and it has been working for most of the different bank websites. What I'm doing is highlighting the price, clicking inspect, then right clicking on the specific line and choosing copy->xpath. Then in google sheets I insert the link into one cell, call it A1, and I insert the xpath into B1. Then in C1 I am doing =importxml(A1,B1). Like I said it works for most other bank websites. But for some reason it's just not working with TD. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am looking for the closing bid price per note. Currently that value is 134.18. Here is the link: https://www.tdstructurednotes.com/snp/noteDetails.action?noteId=1471
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The website you are trying to import() is controlled by JavaScript. Thus, import() functions from google sheets won't be able to fetch the data for you. You may not be able to notice it at first but when landed on the 'I Agree' webpage, the buttons will not be clickable when you turn JavaScript to 'Block'(**Click lock icon beside address bar->Go to site settings->Set JavaScript to 'Block' and reload website using incognito for this case**) for that website.

I suggest finding another source of data that gives the same data.