# Google sheets: IMPORTXML(): How do I get 'datetime'?

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, trustpilot

I am trying to scrape the datetime from the website below using Google Sheets' IMPORTXML() function:
https://www.trustpilot.com/review/zalando.dk?languages=da&page=1

```
<time datetime="2021-03-22T07:25:40.000Z" title="Monday, March 22, 2021, 08:25:40 AM" class="review-date--tooltip-target">Mar 22, 2021</time>
```

I figured out how to get the headlines, review texts and ratings, but I get "NA" when trying to scrape the 'datetime'.
Does anyone know how to do that with Google Sheets' IMPORTXML() function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've [inspected](https://zapier.com/blog/inspect-element-tutorial/) the [website](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/zalando.dk?languages=da&page=1) where you're trying to scrape the `datetime` and I have found that it is being changed dynamically by JavaScript. Thus, that is the reason why you're getting an `#N/A` result on your Spreadsheet.

This is because [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342) function in Google Sheets can only scrape data from a website that isn't controlled by a script. You can also refer to the answer from this post [importxml function in google sheets not working for specific website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820158/importxml-function-in-google-sheets-not-working-for-specific-website) for more information.